# Primary-, foreign keys and relationship model

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, primary-key, relationship

For my homework, we need to create a sql database model on paper, but I'm stuck at the following subject:

We have different people, with some data assigned to them:

Person table:

- person_id (Primary key)
- person_name
- person_number
- .....

Now we have to create a talent table, for every person has some kind of talent (IT, Art, singing, ...) and it has to be linked somehow. The catch here is that a person can have multiple talents(IT and art together).

What's the best way to create this relationship between those 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another table `person_talent` with

```
person_id
talent_id
```

**Talent_table**

```
1 talent_id talent_name
2 talent_id talent_name
3
4
.........
```

**Person_table**

```
person_id
...........
```

whenever person adds new talent insert `talent_id` and `person_id` into `talent_person` table
and delete the record whenever person removes that talent.

Hope it helps

Comment: That looks okay :) Had trouble figuring it out, but when marc_s did the edit, it was all clear :) Thanks both of you !